# Can I make this Clojure code (scoring a graph bisection) more efficient?

Tags: performance, clojure

My code is spending most of its time scoring bisections: determining how many edges of a graph cross from one set of nodes to the other.

Assume `bisect` is a set of half of a graph's nodes (ints), and `edges` is a list of (directed) edges `[ [n1 n2] ...]` where `n1,n2` are also nodes.

```
(defn tstBisectScore
  "number of edges crossing bisect"
  ([bisect edges]
   (tstBisectScore bisect 0 edges))

  ([bisect nx edge2check]
   (if (empty? edge2check)
     nx

     (let [[n1 n2] (first edge2check)
           inb1 (contains? bisect n1)
           inb2 (contains? bisect n2)]
       (if (or (and inb1 inb2)
               (and (not inb1) (not inb2)))
         (recur bisect nx (rest edge2check))
         (recur bisect (inc nx) (rest edge2check))))

     )))
```

The only clues I have via sampling the execution of this code (using VisualVM) shows most of the time spent in `clojure.core$empty_QMARK_`, and most of the rest in `clojure.core$contains_QMARK_`. (`first` and `rest` take only a small fraction of the time.) (See attached [image: screenshot].

Any suggestions as to how I could tighten the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I would say that you haven't expanded that profile deep enough. `empty?` is not an expensive function in general. The reason it is taking up all your time is almost surely because the input to your function is a lazy sequence, and `empty?` is the poor sap whose job it is to look at its elements first. So all the time in `empty?` is probably actually time you should be accounting to whatever generates the input sequence. You could confirm this by profiling `(tstBisectScore bisect (doall edges))` and comparing to your existing profile of `(tstBisectScore bisect edges)`.

Assuming that my hypothesis is true, almost 80% of your real workload is probably in generating the bisects, not in scoring them. So anything we do in this function can get us at most a 20% speedup, even if we replaced the whole thing with `(map (constantly 0) edges)`.

Still, there are many local improvements to be made. Let's imagine we've determined that producing the input argument is as efficient as we can get it, and we need more speed.

- When iterating eagerly over something, use `next` instead of `rest`. The point of `rest` is that it's a bit lazier, and always returns a non-nil sequence instead of peeking to see if there is a next element. If you know you will need the next element anyway, use `next` to get both bits of information at once.
- In general, `empty?` is not an efficient way to test a sequence. `(defn empty? [x] (not (seq x)))` is obviously a wasted `not`. If you care about efficiency, write `(seq x)` instead, and invert your `if` branches. Better still, if you know `x` is the result of a `next` call, it can never be an empty sequence: only nil, or a non-empty sequence. So just write `(if x ...)`.
- ```
  (or (and inb1 inb2)
      (and (not inb1) (not inb2)))
  ```

  is a very expensive way to write `(= inb1 inb2)`.

So for starters, you could instead write

```
(defn tstBisectScore
  ([bisect edges] (tstBisectScore bisect 0 (seq edges)))
  ([bisect nx edges]
   (if edges
     (recur bisect (let [[n1 n2] (first edges)
                         inb1 (contains? bisect n1)
                         inb2 (contains? bisect n2)]
                     (if (= inb1 inb2) nx (inc nx)))
            (next edges))
     nx)))
```

Note that I've also rearranged things a bit, by putting the `if` and `let` inside of the `recur` instead of duplicating the other arguments to the `recur`. This isn't a very popular style, and it doesn't matter to efficiency. Here it serves a pedagogical purpose: to draw your attention to the basic structure of this function that you missed. Your whole function has the structure`(if xs (recur (f acc x) (next xs)))`. This is exactly what `reduce` already does!

I could write out the translation to use `reduce`, but first I'll also point out that you also have a `map` step hidden in there, mapping some elements to 1 and some to 0, and then your reduce phase is just summing the list. So, instead of using lazy sequences to do that, we'll use a transducer, and avoid allocating the intermediate sequences:

```
(defn tstBisectScore [bisect edges] 
  (transduce (map (fn [[n1 n2]]
                    (if (= (contains? bisect n1)
                           (contains? bisect n2)
                       0, 1)))
             + 0 edges))
```

This is a lot less code because you let existing abstractions do the work for you, and it should be more efficient because (a) these abstractions don't make the local mistakes you did, and (b) they also handle chunked sequences more efficiently, which is a sizeable boost that comes up surprisingly often when using basic tools like `map`, `range`, and `filter`.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much @amalloy.  your answer explains the `empty?` time, motivates transducers, and highlights my stupid miss of `(= inb1 inb2)` (:

Comment: but coding up your two suggestions as tstBisectScore3 and tstBisectScore4, compared to my original tstBisectScore1, criterium gives these mean execution times: tstBisectScore1 mean exec = 55.5 µs, tstBisectScore3: 48.87, tstBisectScore4: 58.02 ?!  your recurrence version seems best?

Comment: It could be. There is some abstraction in using transducers, which isn't totally free. If your input actually is a lazy seq, the manual recursion is the most direct way to consume it. The transducers version is simplest, and will be more efficient for some kinds of inputs (e.g. something generated by `range` + `map`), but not all inputs.

Comment: ack! one more interesting factoid: replacing the `contains?` tests with `.contains ^clojure.lang.IPersistentSet` (as suggested by Eugene over on ask.clojure and @marti below) improves things further: mean exec=37.23!  thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based [this answer from amalloy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73848605) and shows some additional ways to speed up this code:

- **Use Java arrays**:

Convert `edges` with `(into-array (map into-array edges))`. This allows you to use operations like [`aget`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/aget), [`aset`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/aset) and especially [`areduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/areduce).

- **Use Java functions**

In the following code, I replaced `=` with `.equals` and `contains?` with `.contains`.

- **Use type hints**

Using these tips, I rewrote your function like this:

```
(defn tst-bisect-score [^HashSet bisect
                        ^"[[Ljava.lang.Long;" edges]
  (areduce edges
           i
           ret
           (long 0)
           (+ ret
              (let [^"[Ljava.lang.Long;" e (aget edges i)]
                (if (.equals ^Boolean
                             (.contains ^HashSet bisect
                                        ^Long (aget e 0))
                             ^Boolean
                             (.contains ^HashSet bisect
                                        ^Long (aget e 1)))
                  0 1)))))
```

Convert your arguments in advance with `(HashSet. ^Collection bisect)` and `(into-array (map into-array edges))` and then call:

```
(tst-bisect-score bisect edges)
```

Comment: This will certainly make `tst-bisect-score` faster, but isn't it mostly just hiding the real cost? Unless we convert the whole program to use arrays, all the copying on the way into the function costs as much as the accesses in my version. Also, I don't see why you convert to a HashSet - surely the Set we have already is just as efficient.